# How to do querying, sorting and filtering on values of an object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find a way to do querying, sorting and filtering on values of an object(which is again an object) in a mongo document. The document structure is,

```
{
    _id: '',
    uid: '12345',
    objects:{
        dkey1: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            ...
        },
        dkey2: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            ...
        },
        dkey3: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            ...
        },
        dkey4: {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

`objects` property can contain 1000s of objects with dynamic keys. Thery are hash based unique keys. When I get these objects, I don't want to return all. I want to query, sort, limit as it can be done if they are from different documents. For example, if I say `prop1 = val1` sort by `prop2` limit `10`, the query should return first 10 sub-objects in the `objects`, where their `prop1` is `val1` sorted by `prop2`.

I think it cannot be done with normal `find`. So, I am trying with aggregation framework. In first stage I will do match on `uid`. Next? I am confused there. Instead of objects with dynamic keys, if it is an array of objects, I can do `$unwind` and in further stages, I could've done filter on inner properties(`prop1`, `prop2`...), sorting and applying limit etc. But the problem is, it is not an array of objects. If there is a way to convert values of `objects` object into array of objects, it would be easier. I was looking for the way, but I could not find a solution.

I know the structure is not good and changing the schema would help me. But I am in a situation, I cannot change it now. Is there a way to convert `objects`'s values into array of objects? Or is there different way to achieve the same result with some other aggregation pipeline stages?

Answer (score -1):

Why can't this be done with normal find? According to the [documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) aggregation operations is to "group values from multiple documents together", and if I understood correctly that's not what you want to do here.

Try this:

```
db.objects.find({prop1: 'val1'}).sort({prop2: 1}).limit(10)
```

This was tested in mongo shell

- **objects** would be your collection
- the number **1** on sort means ascending order, -1 would be descending
- and the number **10** on limit is the limit value of course

--- Edit ----

If you want to access to properties of documents inside another document, use the dot notation.

Example: `db.objects.find({'nestedobj.prop1': 'val1'})`

--- Edit 2 ---

Now I see I misunderstood your question. Sory. The problem here is that I don't think there is an operator that will let you access any embedded document (I really don't know, I can look into it but not right now).

But maybe I can help you telling you that if you are going to use 'aggregate', '$match' would be to filter the results, so uid wouldn't be on that pipeline stage. MongoDB 2.4 provides support for Javascript functions executed at database, but the purpose of the aggregation framework, as I told you before, is to map reduce the documents, so this isn't the best case scenario. I would be concerned about the performance and the ability of the database engine to accomplish what you want. But I think it should be tested before dismissing the idea.

Sorry again for misunderstanding your question and I hope you can solve your problem. Let me know if you do and how!